# Excluding `commit ...` lines from `git rev-list` command output

Tags: git

In the following command

```
$ git rev-list --format="%aI %H %P" --max-count=2 master

commit b744c3af07a15aaeb1b82fab689995fd5528f120
2019-10-07T11:33:44+09:00 b744c3af07a15aaeb1b82fab689995fd5528f120 417056578a76f87f8175c7b315e35ca2fb92a0aa
commit 417056578a76f87f8175c7b315e35ca2fb92a0aa
2019-10-07T11:33:03+09:00 417056578a76f87f8175c7b315e35ca2fb92a0aa 9728ab488ad2fc5e17daba69cbc80ff514f70da8 cda0d497e31e23898ebc83ca8f5895780ec16432
```

which parameters do I have to pass to `git` so that the lines starting with `commit ...` are not generated by `git`?

Note that I want a strict `git` solution, not a solution which removes the undesired lines from `git`'s output.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git log --pretty=format:"%aI %H %P" --max-count=2 master
```

gives the output you want.

*(The "`commit <hash>`" lines are part of the rev-list base output.)*

Comment: Nice, thanks! What is then the real difference between `git log` and `git rev-list`? Their difference seem blured inside their very similar documentation ...

Comment: In short, `git log` is the porcelain counterpart to `rev-list` which is the plumbing tool. See [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain) for the distinction.

Comment: Does this mean that `git log` invokes and transforms the output of `git rev-list` to do its work and generate its own output?

Comment: @mljrg I'm unsure about that and don't want to botch it. Let me consult my cristal ball. Hmmmm..... yes, I sense that [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) is on his way and will soon give a thorough explanation of what's under the surface we scratched ;-) *(just an intuition of course : lots of other "gurus" here)*

Comment: The `git log` and `git rev-list` programs are both built from a single source file, with two entry points: the `log` entry point sets some options one way and the `rev-list` entry point sets them the other way. That might change in the future: only whatever the documentation actually promises, remains promised. Annoyingly, since `git log` *is* porcelain, it obeys user-defined settings, which is bad for trying to write scripts. There really ought to be a `git rev-list` option for eliminating the `commit <hash>` lines.